# Programmatically Building an Associative Array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I am currently building a questionnaire system which spans over multiple steps (pages). I am using an assoc array which is stored in session to store the submitted answers.

I am having problems getting my head around how I would build this up programmatically.

The array should be as follows

```
array(STEP => array(ANSWER 1, ANSWER 2, ANSWER 3, etc...));
```

I have the step as a variable '$step' and the answer array is built up as a separate '$answers' variable.

So basically what I need to be able to build up is the following

```
array($step => $answers);
```

Comment: I don't understand what's your problem. ```array($step => $answers)``` works fine in PHP. Am I missing something?

Comment: It works as you can see here: http://codepad.org/pgmde2et What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$_SESSION["answers"][$step] = array($ANSWER1, $ANSWER2, <other answers>);
```

It'd be up to you to define `$step` and the `$ANSWERn` variables, of course.  And properly initializing your session, too.

After the questionnaire, you'd just step through your array to extract all the answers:

```
foreach($_SESSION["answers"] as $step => $answer) {
    // magic happens here
}
```

(edit: I slightly modified the `foreach` to give you the `$step` variable)

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = array();

$answer = array();
$answer[0]= "A 1";
$answer[1]= "A 2";

$x[$step] = $answer;
```

Comment: It just creates the array described in the question

Comment: At the very least, it is nice to eval your code and add the output or `print_r()` of the result to your answer... in this case you'd discover that there's a logic bug in your code.